# Using AWK to print 2 columns in reverse order with comma as delimiter

Tags: awk

I want to print 2 columns in reverse order.

What I want:

```
LONGER-NAME-PRINTING,0x8da763b9
NAME-1,0x8da6cec9
LONGER-NAME-PRINTING2,0x8da3e489
```

What I am getting:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { print $2 ,$1}' eol456.txt 

0x8da763b9E-PRINTING
0x8da6cec9
0x8da3e489E-PRINTING2
```

Separately they look fine:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { print $1}' eol456.txt

0x8da763b9
0x8da6cec9
0x8da3e489
```

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { print $2}' eol456.txt 

LONGER-NAME-PRINTING
NAME-1
LONGER-NAME-PRINTING2
```

I am really confused why it is not working as I would expect it to. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check for DOS CRLF endings on your file? See the output of `file eol456.txt`

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { print $2 ,$1}'  file` should work fine. You want line to be `0x8da763b9E-LONGER-NAME-PRINTING`?

Comment: `awk -F, '{sub(/\r$/, ""); print $2, $1}' file` should work for you

Comment: Inian I checked that and it states "eol456.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators".

Comment: RavinderSignh13 I want it to be like this: LONGER-NAME-PRINTING,0x8da763b9

Comment: anubhava that worked! I am really confused on how that works though. Could you please elaborate?